# APT Can't add repositories! Ubuntu 16.04 minimal

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, virtualbox, lxqt

I built a Ubuntu minimal installation (32-bit) to a VirtualBox Machine. Everything worked without a hitch, and the first things I installed were `xorg` and `lxqt`, including dependencies. It booted up fine, and I thought it was working well, until I tried to add a new repository in the terminal.

Here's the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Once I hit enter, I am immediately met with this error:

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

I've also tried this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
```

with the same result. Running `sudo apt-get install firefox` installs Firefox with no problems; it's adding new repositories that causes the issue.
Aside from installing a few programs via synaptic, I have done nothing to the system. I have not un-installed anything.
Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install `add-apt-repository` by

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

See:

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
software-properties-common: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```